Display flex but it always rows display, not column
test my code
hai, i just jump to studying front-end recently. in this test, i wrote this code for landing page. unfortunally, my code doesn't seems work properly. i expect to my code run with column flex display but it display flex rows. i can't find where is my mistake in my code. i wrote display: flex; and flex-direction: column but nothing happen.
happily if someone help to let me know where is my mistake.


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body{
    background-color: #f7f9fd;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 992px;
    margin: auto;
}

.add-cart-con {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px 0 30px;
}

button {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.add-cart-con button,
.modal button{
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #4caf50;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.card-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 20px;
}

.card {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 16px 20px 10px;
    width: 31%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.que-div{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #2d3140;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.ans-div{
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #2d3140;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin: 10px 0 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.show-hide-btn{
    background-color: #4caf50;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.btn-con{
    text-align: right;
}

.edit,
.delete{
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 10px 4px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.edit{
    color: #4caf50;
}

.delete{
    color: #f34444;
}

.modal{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 540px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 35px 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.modal h2{
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2d3140;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}

#error{
    color: #f34444;
}

#close-btn{
    font-size: 22px;
    background-color: #4caf50;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 14px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

label{
    color: #2d3140;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

textarea{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    outline: none;
    resize: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

textarea:not(:last-child){
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

textarea:focus{
    border-color: #2d3140;
}

.hide{
    display: none;
}

.add-cart-con button:hover,
.modal button:hover,
#close-btn:hover{
    background-color: #368339 !important;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css">
    <title>Flash Card App</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="container">
    <div class="add-cart-con">
        <button id="add-cart">Add New Cart</button>
    </div>
    <div class="cards-list">
        <div class="card">
            <p class="que-div">Question</p>
            <p class="ans-div">Answer</p>
            <button class="show-hide-btn">Show/Hide</button>
            <div class="btn-con">
                <button class="edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
                <button class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <p class="que-div">Question</p>
            <p class="ans-div">Answer</p>
            <button class="show-hide-btn">Show/Hide</button>
            <div class="btn-con">
                <button class="edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
                <button class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <p class="que-div">Question</p>
            <p class="ans-div">Answer</p>
            <button class="show-hide-btn">Show/Hide</button>
            <div class="btn-con">
                <button class="edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
                <button class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <p class="que-div">Question</p>
            <p class="ans-div">Answer</p>
            <button class="show-hide-btn">Show/Hide</button>
            <div class="btn-con">
                <button class="edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
                <button class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <p class="que-div">Question</p>
            <p class="ans-div">Answer</p>
            <button class="show-hide-btn">Show/Hide</button>
            <div class="btn-con">
                <button class="edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
                <button class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal hide" id="add-card-modal">
        <h2>Add Flashcard</h2> 
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="error-con">
                <span class="hide" id="error">
                    Input fields cannot be empty!
                </span>
            </div>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark" id="close-btn"></i>
        </div>

        <label for="question">Question</label>
        <textarea id="question" class="input" placeholder="Type your question here..." rows="3"></textarea>
        <label for="answer">Answer</label>
        <textarea id="answer" class="input" placeholder="Type the answer here..." rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>



I tried to made a column display style with flex-direction column but nothing happen. stay in rows.

Try to add any image of your expectations, it's too hard to understand what is your problem

When they align vertically, that's actually a column; if you want them to align horizontally, then that's flex-direction: row

A couple of problems.
One is a typo which would normally just get the question closed. In the HTML you have cards-list but in the CSS card-list.
The second is a misuse of column in flex-direction.
You want it to flex along the row [until it has to wrap]. This is the default direction but this snippet specifically sets flex-direction: row to make it clear.


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #f7f9fd;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 992px;
  margin: auto;
}

.add-cart-con {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px 0 30px;
}

button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.add-cart-con button,
.modal button {
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.cards-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 16px 20px 10px;
  width: 31%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.que-div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #2d3140;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.ans-div {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #2d3140;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 10px 0 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.show-hide-btn {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.btn-con {
  text-align: right;
}

.edit,
.delete {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 10px 4px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.edit {
  color: #4caf50;
}

.delete {
  color: #f34444;
}

.modal {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 540px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 35px 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.modal h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2d3140;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

#error {
  color: #f34444;
}

#close-btn {
  font-size: 22px;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

label {
  color: #2d3140;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

textarea:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

textarea:focus {
  border-color: #2d3140;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.add-cart-con button:hover,
.modal button:hover,
#close-btn:hover {
  background-color: #368339 !important;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css">
  <title>Flash Card App</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="add-cart-con">
      <button id="add-cart">Add New Cart</button>
    </div>
    <div class="cards-list">
      <div class="card">
        <p class="que-div">Question</p>
        <p class="ans-div">Answer</p>
        <button class="show-hide-btn">Show/Hide</button>
        <div class="btn-con">
          <button class="edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
          <button class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <p class="que-div">Question</p>
        <p class="ans-div">Answer</p>
        <button class="show-hide-btn">Show/Hide</button>
        <div class="btn-con">
          <button class="edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
          <button class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <p class="que-div">Question</p>
        <p class="ans-div">Answer</p>
        <button class="show-hide-btn">Show/Hide</button>
        <div class="btn-con">
          <button class="edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
          <button class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <p class="que-div">Question</p>
        <p class="ans-div">Answer</p>
        <button class="show-hide-btn">Show/Hide</button>
        <div class="btn-con">
          <button class="edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
          <button class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <p class="que-div">Question</p>
        <p class="ans-div">Answer</p>
        <button class="show-hide-btn">Show/Hide</button>
        <div class="btn-con">
          <button class="edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
          <button class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal hide" id="add-card-modal">
      <h2>Add Flashcard</h2>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="error-con">
          <span class="hide" id="error">
                    Input fields cannot be empty!
                </span>
        </div>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark" id="close-btn"></i>
      </div>

      <label for="question">Question</label>
      <textarea id="question" class="input" placeholder="Type your question here..." rows="3"></textarea>
      <label for="answer">Answer</label>
      <textarea id="answer" class="input" placeholder="Type the answer here..." rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>




You got a class name wrong. In your CSS you target .card-list instead of cards-list. I removed the flex-direction: column just for referencing and it looks to be working fine.


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body{
    background-color: #f7f9fd;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 992px;
    margin: auto;
}

.add-cart-con {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px 0 30px;
}

button {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.add-cart-con button,
.modal button{
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #4caf50;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

 
.cards-list { /* typo */
    display: flex;
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 20px;
}

.card {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 16px 20px 10px;
    width: 31%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.que-div{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #2d3140;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.ans-div{
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #2d3140;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin: 10px 0 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.show-hide-btn{
    background-color: #4caf50;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.btn-con{
    text-align: right;
}

.edit,
.delete{
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 10px 4px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.edit{
    color: #4caf50;
}

.delete{
    color: #f34444;
}

.modal{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 540px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 35px 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.modal h2{
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2d3140;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}

#error{
    color: #f34444;
}

#close-btn{
    font-size: 22px;
    background-color: #4caf50;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 14px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

label{
    color: #2d3140;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

textarea{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    outline: none;
    resize: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

textarea:not(:last-child){
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

textarea:focus{
    border-color: #2d3140;
}

.hide{
    display: none;
}

.add-cart-con button:hover,
.modal button:hover,
#close-btn:hover{
    background-color: #368339 !important;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css">
    <title>Flash Card App</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="container">
    <div class="add-cart-con">
        <button id="add-cart">Add New Cart</button>
    </div>
    <div class="cards-list">
        <div class="card">
            <p class="que-div">Question</p>
            <p class="ans-div">Answer</p>
            <button class="show-hide-btn">Show/Hide</button>
            <div class="btn-con">
                <button class="edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
                <button class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <p class="que-div">Question</p>
            <p class="ans-div">Answer</p>
            <button class="show-hide-btn">Show/Hide</button>
            <div class="btn-con">
                <button class="edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
                <button class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <p class="que-div">Question</p>
            <p class="ans-div">Answer</p>
            <button class="show-hide-btn">Show/Hide</button>
            <div class="btn-con">
                <button class="edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
                <button class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <p class="que-div">Question</p>
            <p class="ans-div">Answer</p>
            <button class="show-hide-btn">Show/Hide</button>
            <div class="btn-con">
                <button class="edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
                <button class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <p class="que-div">Question</p>
            <p class="ans-div">Answer</p>
            <button class="show-hide-btn">Show/Hide</button>
            <div class="btn-con">
                <button class="edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
                <button class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal hide" id="add-card-modal">
        <h2>Add Flashcard</h2> 
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="error-con">
                <span class="hide" id="error">
                    Input fields cannot be empty!
                </span>
            </div>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark" id="close-btn"></i>
        </div>

        <label for="question">Question</label>
        <textarea id="question" class="input" placeholder="Type your question here..." rows="3"></textarea>
        <label for="answer">Answer</label>
        <textarea id="answer" class="input" placeholder="Type the answer here..." rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>




" I removed the flex-direction: column just for referencing" - I'm not clear what 'for referencing' means here, but in removing it you are making the system use the default which is row so removing it was necessary.

yess, i just to know it. thanks
